# How can I solve an equation system where two variables are multiplying each other? [TI-89]

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

How can I solve an equation system where two variables are multiplied by each other on a TI-89? For example:

$$\begin{cases}
30 - Z + 0.02 \cdot Y \cdot Z = 0\\
50 - Z + 0.02 \cdot X \cdot Z = 0\\
50 - 0.02 \cdot X \cdot Y - X - Y = 0
\end{cases}
$$

I was searching and I couldn't find anything, is it possible?
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: There is no fixed method, you just simplify as you can. Looking at your first two equations, see if you can produce an equation with no constant term and go from there.

Comment: Write a routine for Newton's method in TI-BASIC or find an existing program. That's how you would solve nonlinear equations.

Comment: Express $Y$ by $Z$ from the first equation, $X$ by $Z$ from the second equation, and plug both expressions into the third. You end up with a quadratic equation for $Z$, that shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation becomes $Y=\frac {50(Z-30)}Z$ and the second $X=\frac{50(Z-50)}Z$.  Plug those into the third, note that $Z\neq 0$ so you can multiply by $Z^2$ and you have a quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$30 - Z + 0.02\cdot Y \cdot Z = 0 \tag{1}$$

$$50 - Z + 0.02 \cdot X\cdot Z = 0 \tag{2}$$

$$50 - 0.02 \cdot X \cdot Y - X - Y = 0 \tag{3}$$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $$Y=\frac{50(Z-30)}Z$$ and $$X=\frac{50(Z-50)}Z$$

Then, substituting into $(3)$ we have

$$50 - 0.02 \cdot \bigg( \frac{50(Z-50)}Z \bigg) \cdot \bigg( \frac {50(Z-30)}Z \bigg)- \bigg( \frac{50(Z-50)}Z\bigg) -\bigg( \frac {50(Z-30)}Z\bigg) = 0$$ which, upon simplifying, gives

$$Z^2 - 80 Z + 750 = 0 \tag{for Z≠0}$$

Using the quadratic formula we get $$Z=40 \pm 5\sqrt{34}$$

Can you take it from here?